# Add line after text field

Tags: text-processing

How am I able to add a new line beore a `<` in my data?

My current date looks like

```
<VALUE MAGID="1" MAGNAME="Fireball" TYPE="0" <VALUE MAGID="2" MAGNAME="Heal" TYPE="4" <VALUE MAGID="3" MAGNAME="WeaponAccuracy" TYPE="7" <VALUE MAGID="4" MAGNAME="WeaponGuidance" TYPE="7" <VALUE MAGID="5" MAGNAME="GreaterFireball" TYPE="0"
```

Output should be

```
<VALUE MAGID="1" MAGNAME="Fireball" TYPE="0" 
<VALUE MAGID="2" MAGNAME="Heal" TYPE="4" 
<VALUE MAGID="3" MAGNAME="WeaponAccuracy" TYPE="7" 
<VALUE MAGID="4" MAGNAME="WeaponGuidance" TYPE="7" 
<VALUE MAGID="5" MAGNAME="GreaterFireball" TYPE="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace patterns of text, you can use `sed`'s "s" command, like in

```
sed 's/foo/bar/g'
```

which replaces all occurances of `foo` with `bar`.

Specifically, to add a newline before each `<`, you could

```
echo '<value ... <value ...' | sed 's/</\n</g'
```

If you don't like the newline to be added at the very beginning, you could do this instead:

```
echo '<value ... <value ...' | sed 's/\(.\)</\1\n</g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
sed 's/</\n&/g'
```

- `s` argument tell sed to select and replace a **s**tring[text]
- sed use this format `/selectText/ReplaceText/` --> example, `/<//` this removes symbol `<`, only the first `<`
- to select all `<` you use the argument `g` at the end of your `/select/replace/g`, meaning replace all that you find, e.g., replace all `<`
- `\n` argument to add a **newline** it has to be written with `\`backslash
- `&` argument tells sed to copy and paste everything **after** what's been selected, in this case, `<` **VALUE...**

Answer (score 0):

You may do as the other answers suggest, if you have GNU `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/</\n</g' file
```

However, if you don't have GNU `sed`, for example on macOS or some other BSD system, you may need to use a literal newline in place of the `\n` escape sequence in the replacement text:

```bsh
sed 's/</\
</g' file
```

This looks a bit ugly, but standard `sed` simply does not recognize `\n` as anything other than "a literal `n` character" in the replacement text.

You could work around the ugly syntax by using the `y///` command to replace all `<` with newlines (here, `\n` *is* recognized as "newline") and then re-insert the `<` characters:

```bsh
sed -e 'y/</\n/' -e 's/\n/&</g' file
```

To filter out the first resulting line from this, which will be empty, pipe though `tail -n +2`:

```bsh
$ sed -e 'y/</\n/' -e 's/\n/&</g' file | tail -n +2
<VALUE MAGID="1" MAGNAME="Fireball" TYPE="0"
<VALUE MAGID="2" MAGNAME="Heal" TYPE="4"
<VALUE MAGID="3" MAGNAME="WeaponAccuracy" TYPE="7"
<VALUE MAGID="4" MAGNAME="WeaponGuidance" TYPE="7"
<VALUE MAGID="5" MAGNAME="GreaterFireball" TYPE="0"
```

... but ideally, you'd be using an XML parser like `xmlstarlet` or `xq` on the original XML file, the way it looked before you started to try to reformat it for parsing using line-oriented tools.